# Should the thumbprint be SHA2 in addition to the Signature Hash Algorithm?

Tags: certificates, windows, certificate-authority

I'm looking at a Windows PKI and see that the Thumbprint is SHA1, while the Signature is SHA2 (SHA256).

Is this an acceptable configuration?

Should I recommend that the client update to SHA2 for a Thumbprint?

Would this cause some backward compatibility issues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Computed field

I think that's a **calculated** value by the Windows GUI. And not actually inside the cert. Have a look at the cert itself using OpenSSL. (`openssl x509 -in MYFILENAME.CER -noout -text`)

Here's a blog that talks about this:

- http://morgansimonsen.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/understanding-x-509-digital-certificate-thumbprints/

  > the thumbprint is a computed field, i.e. not a part of the certificate data itself.