# Issue regarding installation of SHA256 scertificate

Tags: tls, sha, sha256, sha2

Can anyone help me with the installation of SHA256 certificate? I have generated the certificate perfectly but there seems to be an error below:

[image: error]

Kindly let me know why am getting the exclamation mark in the yellow triangular box at the Key Usage and why is it showing "Thumbprint alogrithm as "sha1"

Here's the complete look of the certificate data in Internet Explorer.

[image: cert data]

[image: cert data 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Key Usage error

The key usage field shows exclamation mark because this field is marked as critical. This is not an error.

> why is it showing "Thumbprint alogrithm as "sha1"

Beacuse the certificate thumbprint (the field below it) is created using SHA1.

Comment: how to install certificate with thumbprint sha256?

Comment: SHA256 thumbprint does not exist (yet). Thumbprints are made using MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: To have a "SHA256 signed" certificate (to avoid the google chrome warning) you are already good to go. The thumbprint can be SHA1. For example, examine the certificate at https://twitter.com/ and see that it is signed with SHA256 but has a SHA1 thumbprint

Comment: By "SHA256 signed" cerificate, you mean signature hash algorithm. Thumbprint is almost everywhere SHA1.

Comment: The "Thumbprint" field is a "computed field". It's generated by the Windows GUI. See my answer here for details: [Should the thumbprint be SHA2 in addition to the Signature Hash Algorithm?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74389/should-the-thumbprint-be-sha2-in-addition-to-the-signature-hash-algorithm)